# fcgid automatic reload script

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-fcgid

I'm a Debian's user and I'm learning mod_fcgid for apache2.4. I want to use it for coding a python script. When I change my script, I have to reload Apache.

I have seen that mod_fastcgi has an option +autoUpdate but not in mod_fcgid.

How can I do this?